# How can I find a particular row from a particular table?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to find specific field of specific column from a particular table based on user provided value. It is unknown what value contain that specific column field.
To be clear:

```
    Table1
   --------------
   | range|value|
   --------------
   | 100  |0    |   
   | 200  |2    |  
   | 300  |9    | 
   | 400  |15   |
   | 500  |20   |
   --------------
```

From Table1
if user provided value is between 0 to 100 then result will be 0,
if user provided value is between 101 to 200 then result will be 2,
if user provided value is between 201 to 300 then result will be 9
and so on. As example if user provided value is 50 then result will 0, if user provided values is 499 then result will 20.

If range column value is fixed then we can easily find the result using BETWEEN function or <= , >= operator. But here range column value are unknown. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what if the user chooses a number above 500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `ORDER BY` and the `ROWNUM` pseudo column to select only the best row:

```
select value from (
  select * 
    from table1
   where range >= :p_Range
  order by range
)
where rownum < 2
```

Alternatively, you can compute an explicit ordering using the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function and use that to filter the results:

```
select value from (
  select t.*, row_number() over (partition by 1 order by range) as rn 
    from table1 t
   where range >= :p_Range
  order by range
)
where rn = 1
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this (or any other) answer answers your question, please consider accepting it (by clicking the check button next to it).

Answer (score 0):

```
select value
from table1
where range = (select min(range ) from table1
               where range >= :rangeparam)
```

Comment: _surely_ you can do this without a nested query?

Comment: @ninesided, well, this is how I interpreted the question. Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly alternative approach using a common table expression to generate your upper and lower boundaries so that you can use the `BETWEEN` condition:

```
WITH ranges AS (
    SELECT 
          LAG(range, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY range) AS lower
        , range AS upper
        , value
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT value 
FROM ranges
WHERE :rangeparameter BETWEEN lower AND upper;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different approach using analytic function [LAG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm#i1327527):

```
select value from (
  select value, range, nvl(lag(range) over (order by range), -1) prev_range from table1
)
where :rangeparam between prev_range+1 and range;
```